# Is $x \times \frac{1}{x} = 1$ an identity or an equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand an identity to be a mathematical statement that is always true e.g. $x + x = 2x$, and an equation to be a statement that is only true for particular values e.g. $x + 1 = 3$ is only true for one value of $x$. Is $x \times \frac{1}{x} = 1$ an identity or an equation? It doesn't seem to be either since it is not true for all values of $x$, but at the same time it can't be 'solved' like an equation can. Or is it just an identity which is true for all values of $x$ in its domain i.e. all real $x$ except $x = 0$?

Comment: The last thing you said is true: on the domain with $x\neq 0$ the equation $x\cdot \frac{1}{x}=1$ is an identity.

Comment: Who says that an identity cannot have exclusions for certain $x$ values?

Comment: I think in common usage, an "equation" is a problem to be solved (quadratic equation, differential equation), and an identity is a statement, in the form of an equality, that is true in certain well-defined general circumstances.   This isn't a mathematical definition, but a note on English usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion,
an identity is an equation
that is true except
for a well-specified
set of exceptions
(which may be empty).

Your example
($x\cdot \dfrac1{x} = 1$,
exception is $x = 0$)
is one,
as is
$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$
with no exceptions,
as is
$\tan(x)
=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}
$
with exceptions when
$\cos(x) = 0$
(i.e., $x = (n+\frac12)\pi,
n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Answer (score 4):

An equation is any statement with content "equals" other content.

An equation is an identity if it is true for all values in the specified domain (here that would be all nonzero reals or all nonzero values in whatever space you are working in).

To answer your question: it is both (all identities are equations). So, more specifically it is an identity.